# actionscript 3 - how to hide default cursor in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, actionscript, mouse-cursor

is there a way to hide default cursor[flash]when it's opened
using chrome?

i can hide it using ordinary way when it's opened using firefox/IE
but somehow it doesn't work when it's opened using google chrome.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I've tried this

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
Mouse.hide();
```

and it worked for me in google chrome.

Comment: i've try it,and it's still not working in chrome. the default cursor still showing

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a verified bug in Chromium, only on Mac:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32703

Answer (score 1):

The cursor cannot be hidden in Chrome when Flash is running in "opaque" or "transparent" window mode (a bug).

The workaround would be - if your Flash application can run without this mode - to set your wmode option to "window" or remove the option (the default is "window").

The wmode option is something u would change in your HTML file, where either the flash HTML tag is generated or has been put there staticly. Just open up your HTML file and search for the word "wmode".

Answer (score 0):

then try to add a timer first that calls the Mouse.hide() function. Something like:

```
 var myTimer : Timer;
 myTimer = new Timer(300, 1);
 myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);
 myTimer.start();


 function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
 Mouse.hide();
 myTimer.stop();
 }
```